# Android not hanging up when hangup button is pressed

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, phone-app, bugs

*Phone: Galaxy Note 2; I605 (Verizon- Unlocked)*

*Carrier: T-Mobile*

*Rooted: Yes*

---

I have this problem with Android Lollipop where when I cancel a call, the hangup button disappears and the phone says "Hanging Up" but never hangs up. Navigating away from the dialer screen destroys the UI but the calling process still runs in the background to the point where it either goes to voicemail if the other party doesn't pick up or hangs up in case of interactive calls.

This only happens with Android 5.x.x. What could be the problem? Has anybody encountered this and what was your solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your system applications are updated in the play store. the store will contain the latest updates which might have the bug fixes for the above issue.

Android lollipop would have the notification type alert. are you getting it properly? is it possible to hang up the call there?

If still problem persists, then wipe partition cache might solve the issue.

Comment: Actually this was a different problem. I used an At&T ROM on a VZ phone which surprisingly has the required libraries and the problem went away.